# How to make cakephp cacheAction work with multilanguage

Tags: cakephp-2.0

I'm working with cakephp 2.x

I've got a site with static pages (Multilanguage) and cacheAction.

The cache does not recognize the language and caches the page in the firest language....

Any idea how to solve (a part from disabling the cache?)
Thanks,
Massimo

```
class PagesController extends AppController {

/**
* This controller does not use a model
*
* @var array
*/
public $uses = array();
public $helpers = ['Cache','AbTest.AbTest'];
public $cacheAction = '1 month';
public $components = array('AbTest.AbTest');
```

....

```
if ($locale && file_exists(APP . 'View' . $theme_path . DS .     $this->viewPath . DS . $locale .DS. implode('/', $path) . $this->ext )) 
    {       
        array_unshift($path,$locale);
    }

    try {
        $this->render(implode('/', $path));
    } catch (MissingViewException $e) {
        if (Configure::read('debug')) {
            throw $e;
        }
        throw new NotFoundException();
    }
```

I expect the cache to present me ita/pages/who and eng/pages/who as different pages, while it outputs alway ita/pages/who

Answer (score 1):

There is an option for this called `Cache.viewPrefix`. You didn't mention how you manage the languages in your site, but the basic logic is that you can set the cache file prefix with the language and this way you will have separate cache files for every language. For example, you can do it in your PagesController or AppController like

`Configure::write('Cache.viewPrefix', /* place the language here */);`

Comment: I put this line in my AppController, where I set the CurrentLanguage.but I still see the pages in the wrong language, is there any trick I have to follow? Something I've to be careful of?

Comment: No, there isn't anything more than the code line given. If you load different languages with different URL, like language after root - _domain.com/en/page_, cache files will be generated separately even without the configuration line, because cake generates and checks cache on URL base and because of that _domain.com/en/page_ is different page than _domain.com/page_. If your language isn't displayed in the URL, then maybe check when do you call the `Cache.viewPrefix`, in my test i set language and viewPrefix in `beforeFilter`, so i call it every time. Maybe it's some kind of misconfiguration.